# Robust Clustered Standard Errors and Regression Weights in R

Tags: r, regression

How do I run an OLS regression in R that uses both sample weights and robust clustered standard errors? I know that `lm` will accept a `weights` argument, but `plm` — the clustered standard error package that I could find — does not seem to accept weights.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a simple solution using `lm_robust` from the [`estimatr` package](http://estimatr.declaredesign.org/), which you can install from CRAN `install.packages(estimatr)`.

```
> library(estimatr)
> lmro <- lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, clusters = cyl, weights = wt, se_type = "stata")
> summary(lmro)

Call:
lm_robust(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = wt, clusters = cyl, 
    se_type = "stata")

Weighted, Standard error type:  stata 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper DF
(Intercept) 28.54865    4.01353  0.01920  11.2798 45.81749  2
hp          -0.06249    0.01908  0.08191  -0.1446  0.01959  2

Multiple R-squared:  0.5851 ,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.5713 
F-statistic: 42.31 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 3.437e-07
```

You can see more about what exact estimator it is using [here](http://estimatr.declaredesign.org/articles/mathematical-notes.html#lm_robust-notes).

Answer (score 0):

The following [function](http://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/clustered-standard-errors-in-r/) calculates clustered standard errors and because it relies on `lm` can also incorporate weights (I checked and it yields the same results as Stata).

```
cl   <- function(dat,fm, cluster){
           require(sandwich, quietly = TRUE)
           require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
           M <- length(unique(cluster))
           N <- length(cluster)
           K <- fm$rank
           dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
           uj  <- apply(estfun(fm),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum));
           vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
           coeftest(fm, vcovCL) }
```